# Ping google.com to see if vpn-server is up, if down, reconnect to another one

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron, debian

I am using a VPN server on a vps. The VPN service I use can of course go down for a few minutes or maybe even hours by accident or whatever. If it happens, I would like to quickly reconnect to another vpn-server with the command "vpnapp reconnect".

Does anyone know how to do a bash script I will run every minute via cronjob that:

1. Pings google.com

2A) If it can be reached, do nothing

2B) If it cannot be reached - which would mean the vpn server is down/not working - enter terminal command "vpnapp reconnect" which will make the vpn application reconnect to next available server they offer.

Would be so thankful if anyone could help me. I have ZERO programming knowledge. To me this is pure science.

Thanks in advance.
Oski

Comment: Why ping Google and not your VPN server ?

Answer (score 1):

Can it be this simple?

```
if ping -c 4 google.com ; then exit ; else vpnapp reconnect ; fi
```

So if 4 packages are received, meaning google.com can be reached it will just exit the bash script.

if not, then it will just enter
vpnapp reconnect
as a command in the terminal... reconnecting the vpn.

or does it need to be "vpnapp reconnect" embedded in "?

Lol i am so weak at this. I really dont trust my own suggestion anyway so would love to hear a real programmer speak. Thanks!!

Comment: Since you don't need `then; .. else` do `if ! ping -c 4 google.com ; then vpnapp reconnect; fi `.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bash script, you can just add this cron job (with `crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * ping -c2 google.com || vpnapp reconnect
```

- `* * * * *` Run the command every minute.
- `ping -c2 google.com` Send 2 pings to google.com.
- `|| vpnapp reconnect`  mean that if ping failled it will run `vpnapp reconnect`

Comment: Haha! Just when i replied to myself. Thank you so much sir. appreiate it a lot!! The possibilities available in Linux is just wow. You can pretty much do everything it seems.

Comment: Rather than pinging Google two or four times every minute for the rest of eternity—and bearing in mind that `ping` is designed for network testing use cases and recommends against use for day-to-day scripting tasks, particularly in automated scripts—might it be sufficient to perform a simple DNS lookup to check that a given internet address resolves? One possiblity could be `host -rt A example.com`, but other commands like `dig` or `delv` could be used if more granular control over the request is needed.

Comment: Yeah but must specify an external dns server, cause if you have local dns server that cache, it will return results even without internet  connection (at least for dig, don't know for the 2 others). Ping is also present on almost every distro by default, it's not the case for dig, host or delv.